# How to compare an IPv6 is greater/less than in C

Tags: c, comparison, ipv6

Converting an IPv4 with `inet_pton` to compare if it's within a range of IPv4 is fairly simple. However, I'm not sure how to use `inet_pton` and `in6_addr` and see if it's less/greater than another IP. Here's what I was thinking:

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>

  ...

const char *ip6str = "0:0:0:0:0:ffff:c0a8:3";
const char *first = "0:0:0:0:0:ffff:c0a8:1";
const char *last = "0:0:0:0:0:ffff:c0a8:5";

struct in6_addr result, resfirst, restlast;
uint8_t ipv6[16]; // perhaps to hold the result?

inet_pton(AF_INET6, first, &resfirst);
inet_pton(AF_INET6, last, &reslast);
inet_pton(AF_INET6, ip6str, &result);

//assuming inet_pton succeed
if(result.s6_addr >= resfirst.s6_addr && result.s6_addr <= reslast.s6_addr)
    //within range
```

Comment: Presumably you mean the first two `inet_pton`'s to use `first` and `last`, respectively, instead of `ip6str`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, testing whether the address is within a pre-defined range which the code in OP does would be one case. Another might be storing ip addresses in a map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `memcmp` for this since they're stored in network byte order (aka big endian).

```
if (memcmp(&result, &resfirst, sizeof(result)) > 0 && memcmp(&result, &reslast, sizeof(result)) < 0)
```

I think you might've meant `>=` though and possibly `<=` as well.

In fact, you'd have to do it this way for IPv4 as well, at least on little endian machines.

Answer (score 1):

`is_in_network_v6()` is based on great document http://grothoff.org/christian/rmv608.pdf.

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int is_in_network_v6(const struct in6_addr *network,
                       const struct in6_addr *mask,
                       const struct in6_addr *ip)
{
    unsigned int i;
    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(struct in6_addr) / sizeof(int); i++) {
        if ( ((((int *) ip )[i] & ((int *) mask)[i])) != (((int *) network)[i]
            & ((int *) mask)[i]))
            return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    char *ipStr = "2001:db8:8714:3a90::12";
    char *netmaskStr = "ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff::";
    char *networkStr = "2001:db8:8714:3a90::";

    struct sockaddr_in6 ip, netmask, network;
    inet_pton(AF_INET6, ipStr, &(ip.sin6_addr));
    inet_pton(AF_INET6, netmaskStr, &(netmask.sin6_addr));
    inet_pton(AF_INET6, networkStr, &(network.sin6_addr));

    printf("ip: '%s', netmask: '%s', network: '%s': %d\n",
           ipStr, netmaskStr, networkStr,
           is_in_network_v6(&(network.sin6_addr), &(netmask.sin6_addr),
                            &(ip.sin6_addr)));

    return 0;
}
```